# Criar um Elemento Div dinamicamente em JS puro e atribuir um Bg color aleatorio a ele

Tags: javascript

Estou resolvendo um exercício que consiste em Gerar um `div`com 100px **X** 100px e quando o usuário clicar em uma desses quadrados a cor do BG deve mudar para uma cor gerada aleatoriamente, consegui gerar a div quadrada, mais quando criou a `function` que muda o BG dela, mais ela não funcina
não sei se por conta do escopo ou algo assim.
segue o código:

```js
/// FUNÇÃO QUE GERA UMA COR ALEATÓRIA
function getRandomColor() {
    let letters = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    let color = "#";
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
}

// VARIÁVEL QUE GUARDA A COR ALEATÓRIA
var newColor = getRandomColor();

// FNÇÃO QUE CRIA QUADROS NOVOS AO CLICAR NO BOTÃO

function addNewSquare(){
    let divElement = document.createElement('div')//
    divElement.setAttribute("onclick", "changeBg()")
    divElement.setAttribute("class","box")
    document.body.appendChild(divElement)
    

}
//FUNÇÃO PARA MUDAR A COR DE FUNCO DA DIV PARA UMA COR ALEATÓRIA
function changeBg() {
    divElement.style.background(color)
}
```

```css
div{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin:20px ;
    border: 3px solid slateblue;
}
```

```html
    <button onclick="addNewSquare()">Clique aqui</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Faltou pouco, exemplo:

```js
/// FUNÇÃO QUE GERA UMA COR ALEATÓRIA
function getRandomColor() {
    let letters = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    let color = "#";
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
}

function addNewSquare(){
    let divElement = document.createElement('div')//
    divElement.setAttribute("onclick", "changeBg(this)")
    divElement.setAttribute("class","box")
    document.body.appendChild(divElement)
    

}
//FUNÇÃO PARA MUDAR A COR DE FUNCO DA DIV PARA UMA COR ALEATÓRIA
function changeBg(obj) {
    obj.style.background = getRandomColor();
}
```

```css
div{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin:20px ;
    border: 3px solid slateblue;
}
```

```html
 <button onclick="addNewSquare()">Clique aqui</button>
```

Foi adicionado o `this` na função do `changeBg(this)` pra saber qual elemento vai sofrer a alteração e na função foi chamado a outra função `getRandomColor()` para gerar sempre a nova cor.

Comment: Muito Obrigado!